# Использование proto в Qt

Tags: c++, qt, google-protobuf

**Задача:** подключиться с вебсокету livecoin.net (https://github.com/lvcn1/ws-client-examples)

**Путь к решению:**

1. Установил protobuf:

```
vcpkg.exe install protobuf protobuf:x64-windows
```

2. Скачал из репозитория LivecoinWSapi.proto:

```
https://github.com/lvcn1/ws-client-examples/blob/master/proto/LivecoinWSapi.proto
```

3. Скомпилировал proto-файл:

```
protoc --cpp_out=. LivecoinWSapi.proto
```

4. Подключил заголовочные файлы к проекту:

```
INCLUDEPATH += D:/programs/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/include
LIBS += -LD:/programs/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/bin -llibprotobuf -llibprotoc
```

5. И написал 2 строки для теста:

```
#include "network/LivecoinWSapi.pb.h"

#include <QApplication>

using namespace protobuf::ws;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    SubscribeTradeChannelRequest message;
    message.set_currency_pair("BTC/ETH");

    return a.exec();
}
```

**Результат:**
Однако при компиляции ловлю ошибку на каждом использовании proto::ws:

```
ошибка: undefined reference to `protobuf::ws::SubscribeTradeChannelRequest::SubscribeTradeChannelRequest()`
ошибка: undefined reference to `protobuf::ws::SubscribeTradeChannelRequest::~SubscribeTradeChannelRequest()`
ошибка: undefined reference to `protobuf::ws::SubscribeTradeChannelRequest::~SubscribeTradeChannelRequest()`
ошибка: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::fixed_address_empty_string[abi:cxx11]`
collect2.exe:-1: ошибка: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Использую:

- Qt 5.12.1
- MinGW 7.3 64-bit
- libprotoc 3.6.1
- vcpkg 2018.11.23-nohash

**UPD 1:** Решил попробовать CMake, вместо qmake.

- cкачал последнюю версию cmake, подключил к Qt.
- скачал минимальный пример proto с использованием cmake (https://github.com/ttroy50/cmake-examples/tree/master/03-code-generation, https://github.com/shaochuan/cmake-protobuf-example)

Но при использовании компилятора MinGW ошибка: 
`target pattern contains no '%'.  Stop.`
Компилятор MSVC:

```
ninja: error: 'C:/Users/user/Documents/protobuf-test/protobuf/protobuf::protoc', needed by 'AddressBook.pb.cc', missing and no known rule to make it
```

Answer (score 0):

Сгенерированный `cpp` нужно добавить в проект

Comment: Добавил .h и .cc в проект.При инклуде .h - ошибки undefined reference, при .cc - multiple definition